# Winternals Desktops and Outlook 2010 email notification

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, notification-area

I am using Winternals/Sysinternals desktops.exe for multiple desktops.  However, I just noticed that Outlook 2010 does not display the new mail notification on a desktop its not opened on.  Can that be changed so I can see the new mail notification on all desktops?